# Which ports does the Sony Media Controller Android app use?

Tags: android, port-forwarding

I recently got a new Sony Blu-ray player with built-in Wi-Fi.  I downloaded the associated [**Sony Media Remote**](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.sony.seconddisplay.view&hl=en) app for my Android, and got it to work correctly with the player.

My only beef is that the app is said to work only over Wi-Fi. Leaving the Wi-Fi on my phone turned on really eats up battery, so I want to be able to control the player over the cell network.

I'm thinking this should be as simple as port forwarding from my router to the player's local IP, but I haven't been able to find anything on the internet about **which port(s) this app uses**.

Has anyone else tried (& possibly been successful) at this?  Or know of where this information might be listed?

Comment: The question's off-topic since it's about the workings of an Android App (not interfacing with a computer). You can request to have it migrated to [Android.SE] though by `flag`ging it for moderator attention.

Comment: I [disagree that it's off-topic](http://superuser.com/faq).  Questions not to ask includes, `...and it is not about...electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer`, but this is essentially about how to interface with a computer (Android OS) through ports.  It's not specific to that Android app because I could just as well be trying to develop my own desktop application to do the same thing, and I'd still need to know port information.  Nonetheless, I'll flag it for moderation.

Comment: It *is* an Android app, and anything using Android OS is – per definition on SU – not a computer. I mean, if you specifically want to find out the port a program is using, regardless of *where* it comes from, it would make sense (e.g. using [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to sniff the traffic), but then we wouldn't need to know the whole Android and Blu-Ray TV thing.

Answer (score 1):

UPNP/DLNA devices would use port 5000/tcp (say [Skifta](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.skifta.android.app))

Sony may or may not use other ports for remote control. Skifta will not.